# ASP.Net: Authentication via Browser's Login Window

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, security

I have what appears to be a fairly common scenario:  I have a database that contains a list of users/passwords, and ideally, when someone visits the site, I'd like to use their windows name (internal), otherwise whatever name the user provided (external).

My main question is how do I send a response to the browser forcing it to prompt for their username/password for external users (like when you visit a page that uses windows authentication)?  Has anyone done this before?

My main goal is to avoid creating a login screen, and just use what the browser has built in.  Is there a way I can leverage the built in forms authentication to do this?

Thanks!

*Update:  I found something similar to what I was looking for here: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ASP.net Membership libraries with Windows authentication. Here is the [ScottGu blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx) talking about it